Polars/Spark/SQL Standardize similar company names in table column
I have a table with a column of company names. The same company can appear with a variety of names (e.g. 'Ciao', 'Ciao Inc', 'Ciao Inc User').
I want to provide the same company under different names with a unique identifier, as per the following example (assume the arrays are columns):
['Ciao', 'Ciao Inc', 'HB', 'Ciao Inc User', 'HB lmtd'] -> [1, 1, 2, 1, 2]
I would like to achieve this in either Polars, Spark, or plain SQL.
Do you know of any simple way to achieve this?
Thanks a lot

Define the rules to transform a string to a kind of canonical form first. E.g. convert to lower case, remove excessive white spaces, remove words from a stop list (inc, ltd, ..) .. other rules relevant to the problem. Sure they can be implemented with any tool you mentioned.

As mentioned in the comments, there is no canonical way of doing this. In general, you will need to come up with a way to normalize the company names into a common format. Then, such a transformation can be easily implemented.
Example. This simple example uses polars to

transform the company name to lowercase,
remove any combination of suffixes coming from a pre-defined list ("inc", "user", "lmtd").

import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "company": ['Ciao', 'Ciao Inc', 'HB', 'Ciao Inc User', 'HB lmtd']
})

def normalize_company_name(expr: pl.Expr) -> pl.Expr:
    suffixes = ["inc", "user", "lmtd"]
    suffixes_group = "|".join(s + "\\s?" for s in suffixes)
    return (
        expr
        .str.to_lowercase()
        .str.replace_all(f" ?({suffixes_group})+$", "")
    )

df.with_columns(
    normalize_company_name(pl.col("company")).name.suffix("_normalized")
)

shape: (5, 2)
┌───────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ company       ┆ company_normalized │
│ ---           ┆ ---                │
│ str           ┆ str                │
╞═══════════════╪════════════════════╡
│ Ciao          ┆ ciao               │
│ Ciao Inc      ┆ ciao               │
│ HB            ┆ hb                 │
│ Ciao Inc User ┆ ciao               │
│ HB lmtd       ┆ hb                 │
└───────────────┴────────────────────┘

